# Woocommerce - Add text after original price when on sale

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add the text "Highest reported price abroad" after the crossed-out original price on the single product page.

I attempted the method explained here: [WooCommerce: How do you add text before the price and before sale price?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654019/woocommerce-how-do-you-add-text-before-the-price-and-before-sale-price) However, the WooCommerce template seems to have changed significantly since then and I'm unsure how to modify the code given there to work with the new default template.

My client would like to have the "Highest reported price abroad" text be next to the crossed out regular price, but be able to style it separately from the price text. I have tried a plugin that allows adding text before the regular and sales prices, but it was then crossed out as well and couldn't be selected separately using CSS.

Comment: You can likely extend this function to echo the text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43966170/3739498

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a multilingual text after price in woocommerce\_get\_price\_html hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272438/add-a-multilingual-text-after-price-in-woocommerce-get-price-html-hook)